# yii2 Composer Error Exception

Tags: composer-php, yii2

I have been using Yii2 and installing extensions with composer but now I'm am getting an error exception, I have reinstalled xampp and composer but still getting error, below is details of exception, any help would be appreciated.

```
c:\xampp\php>composer install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files

c:\xampp\php>composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:1.0.0-beta4"
Changed current directory to C:/Users/mcdermottd/AppData/Roaming/Composer
./composer.json has been created
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Installing fxp/composer-asset-plugin (v1.0.0-beta4)
    Downloading: 100%

Writing lock file
Generating autoload files

c:\xampp\php>composer create-project --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced yii
-application
Installing yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced (2.0.0)
  - Installing yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced (2.0.0)
    Downloading: 100%

Created project in yii-application
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)



  [ErrorException]
  Argument 1 passed to Fxp\Composer\AssetPlugin\Repository\BowerRepository::c
  reateVcsRepositoryConfig() must be of the type array, null given, called in
   C:\Users\mcdermottd\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\fxp\composer-asset-plu
  gin\Repository\AbstractAssetsRepository.php on line 136 and defined



create-project [-s|--stability="..."] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--repos
itory-url="..."] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--n
o-scripts] [--no-progress] [--keep-vcs] [--no-install] [package] [directory] [ve
rsion]



c:\xampp\php>
```

Comment: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-basic#install-via-composer

Comment: Evgeniy, it was installed and working until I performed composer update.  thanks

Comment: Are you sure that you use `fxp/composer-asset-plugin:1.0.0-beta4` ? And `c:\xampp\php>composer create-project --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-app-basi` <<<< where is char "С" ?

Comment: Evgeniy, I have edited with full new install under new windows profile. Like I said it was working until I did an update. thanks

Comment: You should create issue https://github.com/francoispluchino/composer-asset-plugin/issues

Comment: Your code works for me.

Answer (score 0):

This worked out for me in windows 8.1
1. Ensure also that you have installed composer globally by downloading the composer.exe at composer.org at installation page

2. Open cmd in windows and run php composer.phar global require "fxp/composer-asset-pl
   ugin:dev-master" (ensure that you have defined php in your environment variables

Then run composer self-update...